# How to extract and save a table shown in a specific tab from a website using pandas and python?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to extract this table http://pfam.xfam.org/family/PF00018#tabview=tab9 using python and pandas to dump into a csv file. I have tried:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://pfam.xfam.org/family/PF00018#tabview=tab9'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[0]
```

Using all indexes available for df_list. However, the table of interest is not present.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the table you wanted loaded by Javascript. Open browser's developer tool and you see they load via ajax request at http://pfam.xfam.org/family/PF00018/mapping

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @hunzter's answer, here's some code to load a table from that page:

```py
import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html("http://pfam.xfam.org/family/PF00018/mapping")
print(tables[0])
```